# Executing Perl Scripts from Xcode 4.2

Tags: perl, scripting, xcode4.2, execution

I am a beginner in Cocoa. I am trying to execute a perl script from my class, and I am not getting any results, below is the code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMast, YES);
NSString *documentDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"detect.pl"];

NSMutableArray *someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:path, nil];

[[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/usr/bin/pl"] arguments:someArray] waitUntilExit];
```

I get the following text

```
pl {-input <file>} {-output <file>}
   Reads ASCII PL from stdin (or file if -input specified)
   and writes ASCII PL to stdout (or file if -output)
   NOTE: binary serialization is no longer supported
```

The execution of the code stops right there. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, can someone please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute `/usr/bin/perl`, not `/usr/bin/pl`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am faced with another issue, I might be missing something. Once the perl script completes execution, it displays the result in the NSLog, which is fine. However, Xcode does not evaluate any more code after the perl script execution.

Comment: I'm a Perl guy, not an Xcode guy. so I'm afraid that one's beyond.  Open a new question - I'm sure you'll get some help!